# Spark Window Functions - rangeBetween dates

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a Spark SQL `DataFrame` with date column, and what I'm trying to get is all the rows preceding current row in a given date range. So for example I want to have all the rows from 7 days back preceding given row. I figured out, I need to use a `Window Function` like:

```py
Window \
    .partitionBy('id') \
    .orderBy('start')
```

I want to have a `rangeBetween` 7 days, but there is nothing in the Spark docs I could find on this. Does Spark even provide such option? For now I'm just getting all the preceding rows with:

```py
.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)
```

but would like to achieve something like:

```py
.rangeBetween("7 days", 0)
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.3**

Since Spark 2.3 it is possible to use interval objects using SQL API, but the `DataFrame` API support is [still work in progress](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25841).

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql(
    """SELECT *, mean(some_value) OVER (
        PARTITION BY id 
        ORDER BY CAST(start AS timestamp) 
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS mean FROM df""").show()

## +---+----------+----------+------------------+       
## | id|     start|some_value|              mean|
## +---+----------+----------+------------------+
## |  1|2015-01-01|      20.0|              20.0|
## |  1|2015-01-06|      10.0|              15.0|
## |  1|2015-01-07|      25.0|18.333333333333332|
## |  1|2015-01-12|      30.0|21.666666666666668|
## |  2|2015-01-01|       5.0|               5.0|
## |  2|2015-01-03|      30.0|              17.5|
## |  2|2015-02-01|      20.0|              20.0|
## +---+----------+----------+------------------+
```

**Spark < 2.3**

As far as I know it is not possible directly neither in Spark nor Hive. Both require `ORDER BY` clause used with `RANGE` to be numeric. The closest thing I found is conversion to timestamp and operating on seconds. Assuming `start` column contains `date` type:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row

row = Row("id", "start", "some_value")
df = sc.parallelize([
    row(1, "2015-01-01", 20.0),
    row(1, "2015-01-06", 10.0),
    row(1, "2015-01-07", 25.0),
    row(1, "2015-01-12", 30.0),
    row(2, "2015-01-01", 5.0),
    row(2, "2015-01-03", 30.0),
    row(2, "2015-02-01", 20.0)
]).toDF().withColumn("start", col("start").cast("date"))
```

A small helper and window definition:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import mean, col


# Hive timestamp is interpreted as UNIX timestamp in seconds*
days = lambda i: i * 86400
```

Finally query:

```py
w = (Window()
   .partitionBy(col("id"))
   .orderBy(col("start").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
   .rangeBetween(-days(7), 0))

df.select(col("*"), mean("some_value").over(w).alias("mean")).show()

## +---+----------+----------+------------------+
## | id|     start|some_value|              mean|
## +---+----------+----------+------------------+
## |  1|2015-01-01|      20.0|              20.0|
## |  1|2015-01-06|      10.0|              15.0|
## |  1|2015-01-07|      25.0|18.333333333333332|
## |  1|2015-01-12|      30.0|21.666666666666668|
## |  2|2015-01-01|       5.0|               5.0|
## |  2|2015-01-03|      30.0|              17.5|
## |  2|2015-02-01|      20.0|              20.0|
## +---+----------+----------+------------------+
```

Far from pretty but works.

---

* [Hive Language Manual, Types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-timestamp)

Comment: I use Spark 2.3, but the first option doesn't work for me and throws exception
`scala.MatchError: CalendarIntervalType (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.CalendarIntervalType$)`

There is a JIRA issue that will be fixed in 2.4.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25845

Comment: Hi, for the last query, can I ask you how to include the 'days'? I got "name 'days' is not defined".

Comment: @Spacez the "days" helper function is declared above as a lambda function that multiplies the argument by 86400 (one day in seconds).

Comment: `Window.partitionBy(col("id"), pyspark.sql.functions.window("start", "1 day"))`

Comment: @zero323, would you like to explain whey in window function, you add cast('timestamp').cast('long'),  is cast('long') a must? thank you.

Answer (score 8):

**Spark 3.3** is released, but...

The answer may be as old as Spark 1.5.0:
[**`datediff`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#datediff).

**`datediff(col_name, '1000')`** will return an integer difference of days from 1000-01-01 to col_name.

As the first argument, it accepts dates, timestamps and even strings.
As the second, it even accepts `1000`.

---

#### The answer

**Date difference *in days*** - *depending on the data type of the order column*:

**date**

- Spark 3.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("unix_date(col_name)")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```
- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("datediff(col_name, '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**timestamp**

- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("datediff(col_name, '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**long** - UNIX time in microseconds (e.g. 1672534861000000)

- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.col("col_name") / 86400_000000).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**long** - UNIX time in milliseconds (e.g. 1672534861000)

- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.col("col_name") / 86400_000).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**long** - UNIX time in seconds (e.g. 1672534861)

- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.col("col_name") / 86400).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**long** in format yyyyMMdd

- Spark 3.3+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("unix_date(to_date(col_name, 'yyyyMMdd'))")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```
- Spark 3.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("unix_date(to_date(cast(col_name as string), 'yyyyMMdd'))")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```
- Spark 2.2+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("datediff(to_date(cast(col_name as string), 'yyyyMMdd'), '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```
- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.unix_timestamp(F.col("col_name").cast('string'), 'yyyyMMdd') / 86400).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**string** in date format of 'yyyy-MM-dd'

- Spark 3.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("unix_date(to_date(col_name))")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```
- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("datediff(col_name, '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**string** in other date format (e.g. 'MM-dd-yyyy')

- Spark 3.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("unix_date(to_date(col_name, 'MM-dd-yyyy'))")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```
- Spark 2.2+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("datediff(to_date(col_name, 'MM-dd-yyyy'), '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```
- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.unix_timestamp("col_name", 'MM-dd-yyyy') / 86400).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**string** in timestamp format of 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

- Spark 2.1+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("datediff(col_name, '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

**string** in other timestamp format (e.g. 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss')

- Spark 2.2+

  ```
  .orderBy(F.expr("datediff(to_date(col_name, 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'), '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
  ```

Comment: How can we make this dynamic, i need to give the range starting as first day of the current month and end on current day of the month ?

Answer (score 5):

Fantastic solution @zero323, if you want to operate with minutes instead of days as I have to, and you don't need to partition with *id*, so you only have to modify a simply part of the code as I show:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql(
    """SELECT *, sum(total) OVER (
        ORDER BY CAST(reading_date AS timestamp) 
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 45 minutes PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS sum_total FROM df""").show()
```