# Cannot roll up the rows of a dataframe using pyspark sql window function

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame and I want to roll up the data into 7days and do some aggregation on some of the function.
I have a pyspark sql dataframe like ------

```
Sale_Date|P_1|P_2|P_3|G_1|G_2|G_3|Total_Sale|Sale_Amt|Promo_Disc_Amt|
|2013-04-10| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 295.0|0.0|
|2013-04-11| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 3| 567.0|0.0|
|2013-04-12| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 2| 500.0|200.0|
|2013-04-13| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 245.0|20.0|
|2013-04-14| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 245.0|0.0|
|2013-04-15| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 2| 500.0|200.0|
|2013-04-16| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 250.0|0.0|
|2013-04-17| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 250.0|0.0|
|2013-04-18| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 1| 250.0|0.0|
```

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates)I have applied a window function over the data frame as follows -

```
days = lambda i: i * 86400
windowSp = Window().partitionBy(dataframeOfquery3["P_1"],dataframeOfquery3["P_2"],dataframeOfquery3["P_3"],dataframeOfquery3["G_1"],dataframeOfquery3["G_2"],dataframeOfquery3["G_3"])\
          .orderBy(dataframeOfquery3["Sale_Date"].cast("timestamp").cast("long").desc())\
          .rangeBetween(-(days(7)), 0)
```

Now I want to perform some aggregation i.e. applying some windows functions like the following --

```
df = dataframeOfquery3.select(min(dataframeOfquery3["Sale_Date"]).over(windowSp).alias("Sale_Date"),first(dataframeOfquery3["P_1"]).over(windowSp).alias("P_1"))
```

But I cannot get the desired output. Desired output will be-

```
Sale_Date,P_1,P_2,P_3,g_1,G-2,G_3,Total_Sale,Sale_Amt,Promo_Disc_Amt
|2013-04-10| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 11| 2602.0|420.0|
|2013-04-17| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 7| 1902.0|120.0|
|2013-04-24| 1| 9| 1| 1| 1| 1| 10| 2402.0|120.0|
```

But it is not working. I am stuck on to it. I will be grateful if anyone could help me to sort this out.

Comment: @eliasah . any suggestion?

Comment: what output are you expecting ?

Comment: I have given the sample that I am expecting. Please have a look. I want 7 days rollup. @eliasah

Comment: Do you want more information regarding this? I am confused whether is it a bug of pyspark or I have done something wrong.. :( @eliasah

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't look into that now. I'm really busy. I'll take a look later.