# Using Spark Dataframes, example of using interval in window functions

Tags: apache-spark

I have a DataFrame of orders (contactidid, orderdate, orderamount) and I want a new column that contains, for each order, the sum of all order amounts for the contact for the 12 months prior to this order.  I am thinking the best way is to use the Windowing functions and the new INTERVAL ability in Spark >1.5.

But I'm having difficulty making this work or finding documentation.  My best guess is:

```
 val dfOrdersPlus = dfOrders
   .withColumn("ORDERAMOUNT12MONTH", 
      expr("sum(ORDERAMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CONTACTID ORDER BY ORDERDATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 12 months preceding and INTERVAL 1 day preceding)"));
```

But I get a RuntimeException: 'end of input expected'.  Any ideas of what I am doing wrong with this 'expr' and where I could find documentation on the new INTERVAL literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for now:

- Window functions are not supported in the `expr`. To use window functions you'll have to either use `DataFrame` DSL or raw SQL on the registered table (Spark 1.5 and 1.6 only)
- window functions support range intervals only on for numeric types. You cannot use `DateType` / `TimestampType` and date `INTERVAL` expressions. (Spark 1.5, 1.6, 2.0.0-preview)

If you want to use window functions with date or time columns you can convert these to Unix timestamps first. You'll find a full example in [Spark Window Functions - rangeBetween dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33207164/1560062).