# Rolling average and sum by days over timestamp in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe where the timestamp is in units of days. Following is an example of the dataframe (let's call it `df`):

```
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
| name| type| timestamp|score|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
|name1|type1|2012-01-10|   11|
|name1|type1|2012-01-11|   14|
|name1|type1|2012-01-12|    2|
|name1|type3|2012-01-12|    3|
|name1|type3|2012-01-11|   55|
|name1|type1|2012-01-13|   10|
|name1|type2|2012-01-14|   11|
|name1|type2|2012-01-15|   14|
|name2|type2|2012-01-10|    2|
|name2|type2|2012-01-11|    3|
|name2|type2|2012-01-12|   55|
|name2|type1|2012-01-10|   10|
|name2|type1|2012-01-13|   55|
|name2|type1|2012-01-14|   10|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+
```

In this dataframe, I want to **average over, and take sum of scores for different names over a rolling time window** of three days. Meaning, for any given day of the data frame, and find sum of scores on that day, the day before the considered day, and the day before the day before the considered day for a `name1` . And do similar things for all days of `name1`. And also do same exercises for all kinds of `names` , *viz.* `name2` etc. **How can I do this?**

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806194/pyspark-rolling-average-using-timeseries-data) post, and tried the following

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

days = lambda i: i*1

w_rolling = Window.orderBy(F.col("timestamp").cast("long")).rangeBetween(-days(3), 0)
df_agg = df.withColumn("rolling_average", F.avg("score").over(w_rolling)).withColumn(
    "rolling_sum", F.sum("score").over(w_rolling)
)
df_agg.show()

+-----+-----+----------+-----+------------------+-----------+
| name| type| timestamp|score|   rolling_average|rolling_sum|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+------------------+-----------+
|name1|type1|2012-01-10|   11|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name1|type1|2012-01-11|   14|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name1|type1|2012-01-12|    2|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name1|type3|2012-01-12|    3|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name1|type3|2012-01-11|   55|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name1|type1|2012-01-13|   10|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name1|type2|2012-01-14|   11|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name1|type2|2012-01-15|   14|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name2|type2|2012-01-10|    2|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name2|type2|2012-01-11|    3|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name2|type2|2012-01-12|   55|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name2|type1|2012-01-10|   10|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name2|type1|2012-01-13|   55|18.214285714285715|        255|
|name2|type1|2012-01-14|   10|18.214285714285715|        255|
+-----+-----+----------+-----+------------------+-----------+
```

As you see, I always get the same rolling average and rolling sum which is nothing but the average and sum of the column `score` for all days. This is not what I want.

You can create the above-mentioned dataframe using the following code snippet:

```
df_Stats = Row("name", "type", "timestamp", "score")

df_stat1 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-10", 11)
df_stat2 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-11", 14)
df_stat3 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-12", 2)
df_stat4 = df_Stats("name1", "type3", "2012-01-12", 3)
df_stat5 = df_Stats("name1", "type3", "2012-01-11", 55)
df_stat6 = df_Stats("name1", "type1", "2012-01-13", 10)
df_stat7 = df_Stats("name1", "type2", "2012-01-14", 11)
df_stat8 = df_Stats("name1", "type2", "2012-01-15", 14)
df_stat9 = df_Stats("name2", "type2", "2012-01-10", 2)
df_stat10 = df_Stats("name2", "type2", "2012-01-11", 3)
df_stat11 = df_Stats("name2", "type2", "2012-01-12", 55)
df_stat12 = df_Stats("name2", "type1", "2012-01-10", 10)
df_stat13 = df_Stats("name2", "type1", "2012-01-13", 55)
df_stat14 = df_Stats("name2", "type1", "2012-01-14", 10)

df_stat_lst = [
    df_stat1,
    df_stat2,
    df_stat3,
    df_stat4,
    df_stat5,
    df_stat6,
    df_stat7,
    df_stat8,
    df_stat9,
    df_stat10,
    df_stat11,
    df_stat12,
    df_stat13,
    df_stat14
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_stat_lst)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code to calculate the sum and average of score over last 3 days including current day.

```
# Considering the dataframe already created using code provided in question
df = df.withColumn('unix_time', F.unix_timestamp('timestamp', 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

winSpec = Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy('unix_time').rangeBetween(-2*86400, 0)

df = df.withColumn('rolling_sum', F.sum('score').over(winSpec))
df = df.withColumn('rolling_avg', F.avg('score').over(winSpec))

df.orderBy('name', 'timestamp').show(20, False)

+-----+-----+----------+-----+----------+-----------+------------------+
|name |type |timestamp |score|unix_time |rolling_sum|rolling_avg       |
+-----+-----+----------+-----+----------+-----------+------------------+
|name1|type1|2012-01-10|11   |1326153600|11         |11.0              |
|name1|type3|2012-01-11|55   |1326240000|80         |26.666666666666668|
|name1|type1|2012-01-11|14   |1326240000|80         |26.666666666666668|
|name1|type1|2012-01-12|2    |1326326400|85         |17.0              |
|name1|type3|2012-01-12|3    |1326326400|85         |17.0              |
|name1|type1|2012-01-13|10   |1326412800|84         |16.8              |
|name1|type2|2012-01-14|11   |1326499200|26         |6.5               |
|name1|type2|2012-01-15|14   |1326585600|35         |11.666666666666666|
|name2|type1|2012-01-10|10   |1326153600|12         |6.0               |
|name2|type2|2012-01-10|2    |1326153600|12         |6.0               |
+-----+-----+----------+-----+----------+-----------+------------------+
```