# PySpark: Windowing over partitions and viewing data takes too long

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have been following some of the code here: [pyspark: rolling average using timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806194/pyspark-rolling-average-using-timeseries-data)

and found that after running some rolling average window operations over a data frame of about 25 billion rows, it will take the cluster hours to run: `display(df)` after the operation to inspect its results.

What could be causing this and how might I get around it?

I am doing operations like this:

```
w = (Window()
     .partitionBy(f.col("id"))
     .orderBy(f.col("time").cast('long'))
     .rangeBetween((-3600*2), Window.currentRow))  # 3 hours

df = df.withColumn('rolling_temp', f.avg("temp").over(w))
```

I have tried filtering the dataframe after this operation to reduce the number of rows as well as using `coalesce` to take into account the smaller size to no avail.

Comment: several hours for 25 billion rows sound reasonable to me. It simply takes time for the calculations to run, and the time depends on the hardware that you're using

Comment: You might try filtering **before** doing the operation

Comment: Understandable -- I'll keep playing with it. I need to filter **after** the operation which yields roughly 750 million rows. Running `display(df)` on 750 million rows is taking a very long time, too.

Comment: Why would you want to display 750 million rows? Surely you are not going to parse it manually??

Comment: Well, I just want to glance at the first 1000 rows so I have been using that.