# PySpark / Snowpark calculate running sum between two given dates

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using this sample table:

| id | sales | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2020-04-30 |
| 1 | 6 | 2020-10-31 |
| 1 | 9 | 2020-09-30 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-04-30 |
| 2 | 8 | 2020-08-31 |
| 2 | 7 | 2020-07-31 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-06-30 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-31 |

I would like to calculate the total sum of sales, with the range between two dates.

I assume it would be a window function, partition by id and order by sales_date. But I don't know how to get the sum(sales_date) between two given dates.

```py
win = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('sales_date')
df.withColumn('running_sum',sum(sales).over(win).rangeBetween(start_date,end_date) ??

# rangeBetween of start_date and start_date + 1 year
```

For example;

ID `1` has a start date of `2020-04-30`, and I want to get the sum from `2020-04-30` to `2021-04-30`.

ID `2` has a start date of `2020-08-31`, and the end date would be `2021-08-31`.

Referring to this, it seems quite close to what I want but my problem is that each ID can have a different start-date and end-date for the window sum:

[pyspark: rolling average using timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806194/pyspark-rolling-average-using-timeseries-data)

Comment: Are those `start_date, end_date` a global input? e.g. you need to get all sales from 2020 to 2023? or is this different per id? what happens also if part of the id's transactions are outside the range?

Comment: @IslamElbanna It will not be a global input, has each ID can have a different `start_date`. And `end_date` is 1 year after `start_date`.

The dates are different per ID. Each ID can have sales outside of the range, that is another thing. For now I am wondering how this range can by between given dates. 

I also thought about calculating this separately for each ID in a for loop, and union the dataframes at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

- Use the window function to get the `start_date` of each `order_id`
- Filter any rows which have a difference between the sales date and the start date by more than 12 months (This can be more precise per day)
- Group by `id` and sum the `sales`

**Note: I have changed the input so it can filter the last record as out of range**

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import first, col, months_between, lit, sum, max

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 10, datetime.strptime("2020-04-30",'%Y-%m-%d')),\
    (1, 6, datetime.strptime("2020-10-31",'%Y-%m-%d')),\
    (1, 9, datetime.strptime("2020-09-30",'%Y-%m-%d')),\
    (1, 2, datetime.strptime("2021-04-30",'%Y-%m-%d')),\
    (2, 7, datetime.strptime("2020-07-31",'%Y-%m-%d')),\
    (2, 8, datetime.strptime("2020-08-31",'%Y-%m-%d')),\
    (2, 3, datetime.strptime("2021-06-30",'%Y-%m-%d')),\
    (2, 2, datetime.strptime("2021-08-30",'%Y-%m-%d'))\
    ], ['id', 'sales', 'sales_date'])

win = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('sales_date')
df = df.withColumn('order_start_date', first(col('sales_date')).over(win)) \
    .filter(months_between(col('sales_date'), col('order_start_date')) <= 12)

df.show()
```

```
+---+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|sales|         sales_date|   order_start_date|
+---+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|   10|2020-04-30 00:00:00|2020-04-30 00:00:00|
|  1|    9|2020-09-30 00:00:00|2020-04-30 00:00:00|
|  1|    6|2020-10-31 00:00:00|2020-04-30 00:00:00|
|  1|    2|2021-04-30 00:00:00|2020-04-30 00:00:00|
|  2|    7|2020-07-31 00:00:00|2020-07-31 00:00:00|
|  2|    8|2020-08-31 00:00:00|2020-07-31 00:00:00|
|  2|    3|2021-06-30 00:00:00|2020-07-31 00:00:00|
+---+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

# 2021-08-30 was removed
```

```py
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(\
    sum('sales').alias('total_sales'), \
    max('sales_date').alias('latest_sales_date')\
)

df.show()
```

```
+---+-----------+-------------------+
| id|total_sales|  latest_sales_date|
+---+-----------+-------------------+
|  1|         27|2021-04-30 00:00:00|
|  2|         18|2021-06-30 00:00:00|
+---+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Well it works, but I would also like to select the most recent sales_date, along with other columns. How could I do this, without putting all the columns in the group_by?

Comment: @Dametime you need to add it as another aggregation. I have updated the answer!

Comment: I would like to ask again, right now I could have data stretching for years, how do I calculate like this, for each 12 months between a start date and enddate?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, this `months_between` function can calculate the number of months even if more than a year, so if the difference is 2 years then it will return 24