# Spark ML Transformer - aggregate over a window using rangeBetween

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, apache-spark-ml

I would like to create custom Spark ML Transformer that applies an aggregation function within rolling window with the construct `over window`. I would like to be able to use this transformer in Spark ML Pipeline.

I would like to achieve something that could be done quite easily with `withColumn` as given in this answer

[Spark Window Functions - rangeBetween dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates)

for example:

```
val w = Window.orderBy(col("unixTimeMS")).rangeBetween(0, 700)
val df_new = df.withColumn("cts", sum("someColumnName").over(w))
```

Where

- `df` is my dataframe
- `unixTimeMS` is unix time in milliseconds
- `someColumnName` is some column that I want to perform aggregation.
  In this example I do a sum over the rows within the window.
- the window `w` includes current transaction and all transactions within 700 ms from the current transaction.

Is it possible to put such window aggregation into Spark ML Transformer?

I was able to achieve something similar with Spark ML `SQLTransformer` where the

```
val query = """SELECT *,
              sum(someColumnName) over (order by unixTimeMS) as cts
              FROM __THIS__"""

new SQLTransformer().setStatement(query)
```

But I can't figure out how to use `rangeBetween` in SQL to select period of time. Not just number of rows. I need specific period of time with respect to unixTimeMS of the current row.

I understand the Unary Transforme is not the way to do it because I need to make an aggregate. Do I need to define a UDAF (user defined aggregate function) and use it in SQLTransformer?
I wasn't able to find any example of UDAF containing window function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question for the future reference. I ended up using SQLTransformer. Just like the window function in the example where I use range between:

```
val query = SELECT *,
sum(dollars) over (
      partition by Numerocarte
      order by UnixTime
      range between 1000 preceding and 200 following) as cts
      FROM __THIS__"
```

Where 1000 and 200 in range between relate to units of the order by column.