# Spark Window Range Between N Months for current Date

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, datetime, apache-spark-sql

Normally `rangeBetween` works well if we know the number of days. For example, the following window function:

```
def days(i:Int):Long = i*86400
val w = Window.partitionBy(col("Store")).orderBy(col("mth").cast("timestamp").cast("long"))
   .rangeBetween(days(7), 0)
```

How can we expand this to months, as number of days in a month is not constant? Can I use any month function in `rangeBetween` to solve the problem?

Solution for this Problen

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

spark.sql(
    """SELECT *, mean(some_value) OVER (
        PARTITION BY id 
        ORDER BY CAST(start AS timestamp) 
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS mean FROM df""").show()
```

Comment: If you have Spark 2.3 or newer it's possible that the SQL API works, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates (the answer mentions days but you can try substituting with month).

Comment: @Shaido In that answer he defined the lambda  functions days in the above, how can define months functions, as there are no constant days in a month. In my code also i defined that function. I need something for months.

Comment: Yes, so that part won't work. That's why I mentioned it requires a Spark version >= 2.3 which allows usage like "RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" (here you can try substitute with month).

Comment: Cool it worked out.

Comment: Happy it worked out for you :)

Comment: Cold you share how did you do it? I have precisely the same problem, but I cannot figure out how to implement this in Scala.

Comment: @LucasLima Solution to the problem is updated in the question itself

Comment: Oh, that was the only way, then. I was expecting to be able to build a window object in Scala, not sneaking some SQL query in the code. This doesn't quite work for me - I'll have to try something else. Thank you.

Also, in the question, you are using SQL to create a days window, but I don't see how does that translate to a months window - as you stated yourself, the amount of days vary among different months.

Comment: @LucasLima OVER (PARTITION BY otlet ORDER BY CAST(month AS timestamp) RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 59 MONTHS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

Comment: Does somebody know how to implement this solely using PySpark and not introducing SQL code?