# How to get runtime value of column and used in the next row

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have below dataframe, based on the visited date I need to create a new column allowed- If the customar visted within a week from last allowd week visit I have to mark ***allowed*** as NO **(4th row 2020-01-09-2020-01-10 <7 )** and if it is more than 1 week ***allowed*** yes **(3rd row 2020-01-09-2020-01-01 >7 )**

Input DF

```
Customar  visited_date 

John       2020-01-01   
John       2020-01-05   
John       2020-01-09   
John       2020-01-10  
John       2020-01-17
```

output DF

```
Customar  visited_date allowed 

John       2020-01-01   Yes
John       2020-01-05   No
John       2020-01-09   Yes
John       2020-01-10   No
John       2020-01-17   Yes
```

I dont know how to calulate the colum value in runtime and used that in subsequent column calculation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Window Functions - rangeBetween dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates)

Comment: No, looks like that solution is not work for my usecase.