# How to lag non continuous dates

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to calculate `col(current_month) / previous(month) partitioned by id` the issue is the data is not continuous so I can't do a `lag(price) partition by month` as the previous row to `2018-04-01` is `2018-02-01`.

Instead of my below `example_1` using join or `example_2` using nested when calls I was hoping for a more elegant solution, something like  `lag('price').over(partitionBy('id').rangeBetween('1 month',0)` `<- pseudo code`
is this possible? or is there an 3rd alternative I haven't thought of?

```py
Input:
+----------+-----+--------+-------+
|     month|price|quantity|     id|
+----------+-----+--------+-------+
|2018-01-01| 3.96|    53.0|abc##10|
|2018-02-01| 3.96|    49.0|abc##10|
|2018-04-01| 3.81|   150.0|abc##10|
|2018-05-01| 3.81|    14.0|abc##10|
|2018-06-01| 3.73|    13.0|abc##10|
|2018-08-01| 2.97|    27.0|abc##10|
|2018-09-01| 2.97|    22.0|abc##10|
|2018-10-01| 2.97|    10.0|abc##10|
|2018-11-01| 2.97|    35.0|abc##10|
|2018-12-01| 2.97|    99.0|abc##10|
+----------+-----+--------+-------+

output:
# I need the previous month's column to calculate col(current_month) / previous(month) partitioned by id
+----------+-----+--------+-------+----------------------+
|     month|price|quantity|     id| previous_months_price|
+----------+-----+--------+-------+----------------------+
|2018-01-01| 3.96|    53.0|abc##10|                  null|
|2018-02-01| 3.96|    49.0|abc##10|                  53.0|
|2018-04-01| 3.81|   150.0|abc##10|                  null|
|2018-05-01| 3.81|    14.0|abc##10|                 150.0|
|2018-06-01| 3.73|    13.0|abc##10|                  14.0|
|2018-08-01| 2.97|    27.0|abc##10|                  null|
|2018-09-01| 2.97|    22.0|abc##10|                  27.0|
|2018-10-01| 2.97|    10.0|abc##10|                  22.0|
|2018-11-01| 2.97|    35.0|abc##10|                  10.0|
|2018-12-01| 2.97|    99.0|abc##10|                  35.0|
+----------+-----+--------+-------+----------------------+
```

```py
example_1
lj = df_t.select(
            'id',
            F.add_months('month',1).alias('month'),
            F.col('price').alias('previous_months_price'),
)

df_t.join(lj, ['id','month'], how='left')
```

```py
example_2
nxt_dt = F.add_months('month',1)
df_t.withColumn(
    'previous_month_price',
    F.when(
        nxt_dt == F.expr('lag(month) over (partition by id order by id,month)'),
        F.expr('lag(quantity) over (partition by id order by id,month)'),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the window function, also include the month of the previous row. When calculating the result column set it to null if the difference of the current and previous month is not equal 1.

```python
df = spark.read.option("header", True).csv(...) \
    .withColumn("month", F.to_date("month"))

w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("month")
df.withColumn("prev_qty", F.lag("quantity").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("prev_month", F.lag("month").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("previous_months_qty", F.expr("case when last_day(add_months(prev_month,1)) = last_day(month) then prev_qty else null end")) \
    .drop("prev_qty", "prev_month") \
    .show()
```

prints

```
+----------+-----+--------+-------+-------------------+
|     month|price|quantity|     id|previous_months_qty|
+----------+-----+--------+-------+-------------------+
|2018-01-01| 3.96|    53.0|abc##10|               null|
|2018-02-01| 3.96|    49.0|abc##10|               53.0|
|2018-04-01| 3.81|   150.0|abc##10|               null|
|2018-05-01| 3.81|    14.0|abc##10|              150.0|
|2018-06-01| 3.73|    13.0|abc##10|               14.0|
|2018-08-01| 2.97|    27.0|abc##10|               null|
|2018-09-01| 2.97|    22.0|abc##10|               27.0|
|2018-10-01| 2.97|    10.0|abc##10|               22.0|
|2018-11-01| 2.97|    35.0|abc##10|               10.0|
|2018-12-01| 2.97|    99.0|abc##10|               35.0|
+----------+-----+--------+-------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, What does the rowsBetween(-1,-1) do in this case? I can't see what difference it makes here

Comment: You are right, we don't need this part. I have removed the `rowsBetween` from the code

Comment: `month(month) - month(prev_month) == 1` only works in the same year. use add_months instead

Comment: I was going to say the same but it actually does work because of the orderBy, I feel a bit uneasy about replying on order in spark imo

Comment: I've updated my answer just before your comment, I should've mentioned I already have some working code with your suggestion. I was hoping there would be a more elegant solution out there, in my mind the rangeBetwen would work but if I could lag over rangeBetween one month window but it's either impossible or I'm too stupid to

Comment: @jxc thanks for the hint, I have updated my answer. I have added another `month(...)` call around the the `add_month` in case the day is not always 1. Now there might be an issue when there are 12 months in between two rows

Comment: I know I posted the question but if you look at my example_2 I don't use month() so it doesn't have that issue

Comment: @werner, I think `add_months(prev_month,1) = month` should work. add_months is the function to set the day correctly instead of just 30 days off. or `trunc()` the dates to 'Month' in case some of them are not the first day.

Comment: or `last_day(add_months(prev_month,1)) = last_day(month)` in case the days are different with the original months.

Comment: This brings me to the reason I asked this question, I'm running this on a 1b rows dataframe and these multiple nested function calls add an overhead that is felt more than on smaller dfs, I can't help but feel there's an easier way to do it perhaps with rangeBetween(1 month)

Comment: @Dee, if the months are all saved as the first day of each month, then add_months() should always keep the day to `1`, no need to take last_day()

Comment: @jxc thanks for the `last_day`. I didnt know that function

Comment: @Dee I think at least with `Window` it is not possible to work with dates. If you check the code of [WindowSpec](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f6322d1cb149983fbcd5b90a804eeda0fe4e8a49/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/WindowSpec.scala#L32) you can see that the boundaries are only based on row numbers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates it is possible