# Using rangeBetween considering months rather than days in PySpark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm looking how to translate this chunk of SQL code into PySpark syntax.

```sql
SELECT MEAN(some_value) OVER (
    ORDER BY yyyy_mm_dd
    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 3 MONTHS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS mean
FROM
    df
```

If the above was a range expressed in days, this could easily have been done using something like

```py
.orderBy(F.expr("datediff(col_name, '1000')")).rangeBetween(-7, 0)
```

(See also ZygD's solution here: [Spark Window Functions - rangeBetween dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates))

For a range in months, this however doesn't work as the number of days in a month is not a constant. Any idea how to perform a range considering months using PySpark syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "borrow" the full SQL column expression and use it in PySpark.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2022-05-01', 1),
     ('2022-06-01', 2),
     ('2022-07-01', 3),
     ('2022-08-01', 4),
     ('2022-09-01', 5)],      
    ['yyyy_mm_dd', 'some_value']
).withColumn('yyyy_mm_dd', F.to_date('yyyy_mm_dd'))
```

Script:

```py
df = df.withColumn('mean', F.expr("mean(some_value) over (order by yyyy_mm_dd range between interval 3 months preceding and current row)"))

df.show()
# +----------+----------+----+
# |yyyy_mm_dd|some_value|mean|
# +----------+----------+----+
# |2022-05-01|         1| 1.0|
# |2022-06-01|         2| 1.5|
# |2022-07-01|         3| 2.0|
# |2022-08-01|         4| 2.5|
# |2022-09-01|         5| 3.5|
# +----------+----------+----+
```

Comment: Intervals like that are not yet supported in PySpark, that's why I suggest opting for `expr` and SQL.