# Pyspark find min price within a date range in pyspark dataframe

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a Dataframe which has following data(simulation).

| Price | Date | InvoiceNumber | Product_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.65 | 12/30/2021 | INV_19984 | AXN UN1234 |
| 18.78 | 1/23/2022 | INV_200174 | AXN UN1234 |
| 11.78 | 1/25/2022 | INV_200173 | AXN UN1234 |
| 11.1 | 3/2/2022 | INV_9912 | AXN UN1234 |

I am trying to find minimum price of the product in the last 30days, 60days and 90days without filtering the data. This data is huge and hence avoiding join operation so using a window function. But It returns null.

```
wi = Window.partitionBy("Product_Type").orderBy("Date").rowsBetween(30 ,Window.currentRow)
f1 = df.withColumn("minPrice30",F.min("price").over(wi))
```

Expected output is :

| minPrice60 | minPrice30 | Price | Date | InvoiceNumber | Product_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.65 | 12.65 | 12.65 | 12/30/2021 | INV_19984 | AXN UN1234 |
| 12.65 | 12.65 | 18.78 | 1/23/2022 | INV_200174 | AXN UN1234 |
| 11.78 | 11.78 | 11.78 | 1/25/2022 | INV_200173 | AXN UN1234 |
| 11.1 | 11.1 | 11.1 | 3/2/2022 | INV_9912 | AXN UN1234 |

Is there any way we can achieve this within the date range?
Kindly Suggest

Comment: `rowsBetween` is based on the # of rows in dataframe and `rowsBetween(30, currentRow)` means you are aggregating between `((current row+30)th row) and (current row)` which doesn't exist. `rowsBetween(-30, currentRow)` or `rowsBetween(currentRow, 30)` would make a valid range but this is again based on the # of rows. What you are looking for is window based on time interval. For that, you should use `rangeBetween`. Check this for how to use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates

Comment: @Emma Indeed I tried rangebetween option like .rangeBetween(60,currentrow) since I am comparing against Date and 60 being int it was throwing error.  I just tried in spark sql way and looks like it is working. I missed to use Interval keyword with range in my earlier try. Thanks for showing me the right way to use it :-)

Comment: `currentRow = 0th`,  so `rangeBetween(60th, 0th)` is not a valid range.  you need `rangeBetween(-60th, 0th)`.  And also you need to `unix_date` or `datediff` in the `orderBy` to convert the datetime type to int.  Check your current data type for "Date" and use the corresponding one in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72854840/2956135.