# PySpark group by with rolling window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, window-functions, spark-window-function

Suppose I have a table with three columns: `dt`, `id` and `value`.

```py
df_tmp = spark.createDataFrame([('2023-01-01', 1001, 5),
                                ('2023-01-15', 1001, 3),
                                ('2023-02-10', 1001, 1),
                                ('2023-02-20', 1001, 2),
                                ('2023-01-02', 1002, 7),
                                ('2023-01-02', 1002, 6),
                                ('2023-01-03', 1002, 1)],
                               ["date", "id", "value"])
df.show()
# +----------+----+-----+
# |      date|  id|value|
# +----------+----+-----+
# |2023-01-01|1001|    5|
# |2023-01-15|1001|    3|
# |2023-02-10|1001|    1|
# |2023-02-20|1001|    2|
# |2023-01-02|1002|    7|
# |2023-01-02|1002|    6|
# |2023-01-03|1002|    1|
# +----------+----+-----+
```

I would like to compute the 30-day rolling sum of `value` grouped by `id` for every `date`, and additionally, a number of distinct dates that the `id` was *seen*. Something that would look like this:

```
+----------+----+-----+----------------+-------------------------+
|      date|  id|value|30_day_value_sum|days_seen_in_past_30_days|
+----------+----+-----+----------------+-------------------------+
|2023-01-01|1001|    5|               0|                        0|
|2023-01-15|1001|    3|               0|                        1|
|2023-02-10|1001|    1|               3|                        1|
|2023-02-20|1001|    2|               1|                        2|
|2023-01-02|1002|    7|               0|                        0|
|2023-01-02|1002|    6|               7|                        1|
|2023-01-03|1002|    1|              13|                        2|
+----------+----+-----+----------------+-------------------------+
```

I suspect one could do it using `Window` but am not clear about the explicit details.

Comment: it is unclear, from the input data, how you got 20.3?

Comment: @samkart edited the toy example to make it right.

Comment: I believe the sum is incorrect for id=1001. Also, why is it that id=1002 has two identic dates 2023-01-02, but calculations are different in those rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that originally you have *date* data type in your dataframe, so I used a bit modified input than yours:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df_tmp = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('2023-01-01', 1001, 5),
     ('2023-01-15', 1001, 3),
     ('2023-02-10', 1001, 1),
     ('2023-02-20', 1001, 2),
     ('2023-01-01', 1002, 7),
     ('2023-01-02', 1002, 6),
     ('2023-01-03', 1002, 1)],
    ["date", "id", "value"]
).withColumn('date', F.col('date').cast('date'))
```

In this case, the following window should work:

```py
w = W.partitionBy('id').orderBy(F.expr("unix_date(date)")).rangeBetween(-30, -1)
df = df_tmp.withColumn('30_day_value_sum', F.sum('value').over(w)) \
           .withColumn('days_seen_in_past_30_days', F.count('id').over(w))
df = df.fillna(0, subset=['30_day_value_sum'])

df.show()
# +----------+----+-----+----------------+-------------------------+
# |      date|  id|value|30_day_value_sum|days_seen_in_past_30_days|
# +----------+----+-----+----------------+-------------------------+
# |2023-01-01|1001|    5|               0|                        0|
# |2023-01-15|1001|    3|               5|                        1|
# |2023-02-10|1001|    1|               3|                        1|
# |2023-02-20|1001|    2|               1|                        1|
# |2023-01-01|1002|    7|               0|                        0|
# |2023-01-02|1002|    6|               7|                        1|
# |2023-01-03|1002|    1|              13|                        2|
# +----------+----+-----+----------------+-------------------------+
```

If you have *string* type in the "date" column, then you should use the following .orderBy` clause:

```py
.orderBy(F.expr("unix_date(to_date(date))")).rangeBetween(-30, -1)
```

More options and details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207164/spark-window-functions-rangebetween-dates/72854840#72854840).